# Error connecting Windows 10 PCs to a MAC on a LAN

Tags: networking, mac, connection

**The Setup:**

1x Mac Mini (MM), running OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6(not Mac server)

5x Windows 10 (W10) PCs

1x LAN wifi

1x LAN ethernet

**The Challenge:**

Connect all 5 PCs to the MM over the wired LAN or Wifi and map folders on the MM as additional Drives (Eg, P, Q, R etc) on the W10 PCs, as so as to share files stored on the MM. BTW: The MM is not used as a workstation, more as a "server" or pseudo-server.

**The Method:**

From the PCs Command prompt on the W10 PCs run "net use T: "\1nn.nnn.1.14\fff\fff" /persistent:yes. (real values hidden for security)

**The Initial Outcome:**

2 of the 5 PCs connected and drive letters assigned - no problems,

3 of the PCs could not connect, error message 71, "No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept."

**Attempted Solution:**

On the W10 PCs; increased the number of currentlogons in the registry from 10 to 100, but this made no difference. I think i should be doing something like this on the MM...

**Second Outcome:**

No effect.

**Question:**

How do I increase the number of (network?) connections that the MM can accept? I believe this would solve the issue, but if I'm barking up the wrong tree, I would gladly be pointed to another one.

Thanks in Advance
Dave

Answer (score 2):

I'm told that to raise that limit on a Mac you need to run this in Terminal:
`sudo serveradmin settings smb:MaxClients=-1`
(The -1 meaning "unlimited".)
I can't vouch for that information. I never had reason to try it myself.

On your Mac (really old OS) the limit is 10 connections (Same as Windows prior to Win8).
Newer Mac's and Windows systems use 20.
On newer Mac's you can also install the Server.app (about $25 in the App store) which essentially turns any Mac into a MAC Server and also removes the connection limit. (Besides doing a lot of other stuff.)

Bear in mind that Windows, as a client, is extremely sloppy with these connections and it is perfectly normal that

1. A Windows client doesn't disconnect a previous connections and just opens a new one.
2. Uses more than one connenction in parallel anyway.

This makes it entirely possible that even with just 2 or 3 clients the limit of 10 is already exceeded. (Microsoft "solves" that in their own operating systems by just counting computers in stead of actual connections.)

Comment: Hi Tonny,

Thanks for that very informative reply! 

I will try your suggestions and let you know how I got on.

Thanks again
BR
Dave